# In mootools how do you delay the next method?

Tags: ajax, mootools

i want to put a delay in between reveal() and dissolve().

```
$('foo').reveal().set('html','my message').delay(500).dissolve();
```

I can see that this is not correct but I cannot figure out the right way to do it?

Any help?

**Solved:**

after messing around i realized that delay should go on the item you want to delay instead of on the item that comes before the delay.

```
$('foo').reveal().set('html','test');
(function(){$('foo').dissolve();}).delay(4000);
```

Comment: Where did you come up with that?  It doesn't remotely resemble any example usage of the delay function.  Take a look at the documentation.

Comment: i dont understand the documentation. This is how it would be done in jQuery. I see that you add delay() to the end of a function but im not sure how to use these 3 methods all together (or if i even should). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the delay to start 'after' the reveal has finished, you could do:

```
var element = $('foo');

element
    .set('html','my message')
    .reveal()
    .get('reveal').chain(function(){
        //you're sure reveal has finished!
        (function(){element.dissolve()}).delay(500); //delay the dissolve
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/JNvPM/

Comment: why not `element.set({html: 'my message', reveal: {link: "chain"}}).reveal().get("reveal").wait(500).dissolve();`

Comment: U're right.. I totally forgot about 'wait'.. definitively better, yes :), but the final result is the same :P

Answer (score 0):

In Mootools you need the chain method to do this.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class.Extras#Chain:chain

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Class/Chain.Wait